# How to install laravel by global installation process on window 11. shown this Error in CMD terminal

Tags: laravel

C:\Users\lenovo>composer global require laravel/installer
Changed current directory to C:/Users/lenovo/AppData/Roaming/Composer
Info from https://repo.packagist.org: #StandWithUkraine
./composer.json has been created
Running composer update laravel/installer
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Lock file operations: 11 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

- Locking laravel/installer (v4.5.0)
- Locking psr/container (2.0.2)
- Locking symfony/console (v6.3.0)
- Locking symfony/deprecation-contracts (v3.3.0)
- Locking symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.27.0)
- Locking symfony/polyfill-intl-grapheme (v1.27.0)
- Locking symfony/polyfill-intl-normalizer (v1.27.0)
- Locking symfony/polyfill-mbstring (v1.27.0)
- Locking symfony/process (v6.3.0)
- Locking symfony/service-contracts (v3.3.0)
- Locking symfony/string (v6.3.0)
  Writing lock file
  Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
  Package operations: 11 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  Failed to download symfony/process from dist: The zip extension and unzip/7z commands are both missing, skipping.
  The php.ini used by your command-line PHP is: C:\xampp\php\php.ini
  Now trying to download from source

In GitDownloader.php line 82:

git was not found in your PATH, skipping source download

composer global require laravel/installer

laravel new example-app
this command is not working.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: can you uninstall composer , delete php environment variable . after that again install composer . try again